# How can I call native Wifi functions?

Tags: c#, winapi

How can I call native Wifi Functions in C#, like this one

```
DWORD WINAPI WlanHostedNetworkForceStart(
  _In_        HANDLE hClientHandle,
  _Out_opt_   PWLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_REASON pFailReason,
  _Reserved_  PVOID pvReserved
);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd439488(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Try searching for [P/Invoke](https://www.google.com/search?q=P%2FInvoke&oq=P%2FInvoke&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j69i58j0l3.2538j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8), *or* combine that with the function and get [here](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/wlanapi/WlanHostedNetworkForceStart.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the types that will be used and declare the method. See the [Platform Invoke Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for a detailed explanation.

To get you started, you'll need the `WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_REASON` enumeration:

```
public enum WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_REASON
{
    wlan_hosted_network_reason_success = 0,
    wlan_hosted_network_reason_unspecified,
    wlan_hosted_network_reason_bad_parameters,
    wlan_hosted_network_reason_service_shutting_down,
    wlan_hosted_network_reason_insufficient_resources,
    wlan_hosted_network_reason_elevation_required,
    wlan_hosted_network_reason_read_only,
    wlan_hosted_network_reason_persistence_failed,
    wlan_hosted_network_reason_crypt_error,
    wlan_hosted_network_reason_impersonation,
    wlan_hosted_network_reason_stop_before_start,
    wlan_hosted_network_reason_interface_available,
    wlan_hosted_network_reason_interface_unavailable,
    wlan_hosted_network_reason_miniport_stopped,
    wlan_hosted_network_reason_miniport_started,
    wlan_hosted_network_reason_incompatible_connection_started,
    wlan_hosted_network_reason_incompatible_connection_stopped,
    wlan_hosted_network_reason_user_action,
    wlan_hosted_network_reason_client_abort,
    wlan_hosted_network_reason_ap_start_failed,
    wlan_hosted_network_reason_peer_arrived,
    wlan_hosted_network_reason_peer_departed,
    wlan_hosted_network_reason_peer_timeout,
    wlan_hosted_network_reason_gp_denied,
    wlan_hosted_network_reason_service_unavailable,
    wlan_hosted_network_reason_device_change,
    wlan_hosted_network_reason_properties_change,
    wlan_hosted_network_reason_virtual_station_blocking_use,
    wlan_hosted_network_reason_service_available_on_virtual_station 
}
```

Next, define the native method:

```
[DllImport("Wlanapi.dll", EntryPoint = "WlanHostedNetworkForceStart")]
public static extern uint WlanHostedNetworkForceStart(
    IntPtr hClientHandle, 
    [Out] out WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_REASON pFailReason, 
    IntPtr pvReserved);
```

The you can simply call it from anywhere in your C# code:

```
WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_REASON failReason;
var result = WlanHostedNetworkForceStart(myClientHandle, out failReason, myReserved);
```